# Sort an array of model objects inside another model object

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an array of custom object named `MYView`. It contains an array of custom objects called `Notification`. In `Notification` I have a property called `color` which contains a value between 1 and 6. I need to sort the array of `MYView` objects based on the following criteria.

**Class structures of MYView**

```
@interface MYView : NSObject

@property (nonatomic)                      NSInteger viewID;

@property (nonatomic)                      NSInteger userId;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic)    NSString  *viewName;

@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong)    NSString  *viewCreaterName;

@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong)    NSArray *arrayOfNotifications; // This contains notification objects </i>
```

**Class Notification**

```
@interface Notification : NSObject

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSInteger sColorStatus; // This contains severity value. i.e 6,5..1. 
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSInteger iNotificationID;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *warningName;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *warningIcon;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSArray  *rReplacementValuesArray;</i>
```

1. The severity of a warning.

   - The view with the most severe warning will be listed at the top.
   - Secondarily, the order is based on the number of severe warnings. If several views have severe warnings, the view with the largest number of the most severe warnings will be placed at the top of the list.
2. Number of Notification

   - While severity takes precedence over volume, the second sorting parameter is based on the number of Notification.
   - If several views have the same number of Notification at the same level of severity, the list is ordered alphabetically.
3. Alpha order

   - If there are no warnings present, the list will be organized alphabetically.

I tried a lot to implement using sort descriptor but I failed in fulfilling all the criteria.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: You should use a custom block comparator in `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`.